# How to animated progress bar with string values such as "2/3" flutter

Tags: flutter

I am displaying the string values "1/2", "3/4" inside the SimpleCircularProgressBar and they do not animate like they have to, meaning to do a circular progress bar animation based on the number. So, if I use like an int value 10, 20, it will show etc it shows. So, can someone help, with the string values I used.

This is my code below:

```
final String? awayTeamStatsValue = "1/2"
 SimpleCircularProgressBar(
                  size: 80,
                  progressStrokeWidth: 8,
                  backStrokeWidth: 8,
                  backColor: Colors.black,
                  progressColors: [homeTeamColor],
                  maxValue: 100,
                  value: double.tryParse(awayTeamStatsValue!) ?? 0,
                  animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1200),
                  onGetText: (double value) {
                    return Text(
                      awayTeamStatsValue!,
                      style: FootballStatsHelper()
                          .fAntonS20W400(color: homeTeamColor),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

Your help will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The animated - the loaded percentage is calculated as: currentValue/maxValue. You're using `ProgressBar` wrong way. If you want it to display the same as your `awayTeamStatsValue`, you can do in this way:

```dart
value: (double.tryParse(awayTeamStatsValue!) ?? 0) * 100,
```

100 is your `maxValue` based on your provide code .

Comment: Hi @nguyenfamily thanks, based on my code, I was already displaying the values 1/2 as they are. The issue is the progress bar is not animating, like for example, if the value is 1/2, the progress bar should animate until half of the progress bar, if it's 2/2, it should animate the whole screen like it is 100%  and like that. That is what I want to achieve.